# MySQL 8 Recursive CTE Error Code: 1054. Unknown column

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

This MySQL 8 query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n) 
AS (
      SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
        n + 1 
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 3
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_count;
```

Produces:

```
+------+
| n    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
```

But this one:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n) 
AS (
      SELECT 1
        ,"one" as `one`
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
        n + 1 
        ,"one" as `one`
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 3
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_count;
```

generates the error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'n' in 'field list'

Can you explain why and how to solve that error?

What is the meaning of `(n)` after `WITH RECURSIVE cte_count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways that you can write this.
Without declaring the column names alongside with the cte's name:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count  
AS (
      SELECT 1 as n
        ,'one' as `one`
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
        n + 1 
        ,'one'
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 3
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_count;
```

and declaring them without the need to alias them inside the query's body:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n, `one`) 
AS (
      SELECT 1
        ,'one'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
        n + 1 
        ,'one' 
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 3
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte_count;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look at `WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n)` in a more abstract way.
You always need `WITH RECURSIVE` for your recursive query followed by a name for it (in your case `cte_count`).

What follows next is a comma separated list which defines the number of attributes for your query as well as the respective names for your columns (e.g. `(n)`).

The problem in the second query is that you introduced a new column with `"one" as 'one'`.

Try to only write `"one"` instead of `"one" as 'one'` (both times!) and make `(n)` to `(n, one)` to fix your problem.